# Book for vector-valued integration?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am reading *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions* by E. M. Stein. In the second chapter the Calderón–Zygmund theory of singular integrals are extended to Hilbert space valued functions. However, the theory for integration of these vector-valued functions are only mentioned briefly. In particular, I have the following doubts:

1. What is the difference between strongly measurable and weakly measurable, and is that a big problem (for investigations in harmonic analysis)?
2. Why do we have $(L^p)'\cong L^{p'}$ in this case? The proof for $\mathbb{R}$ uses the Radon–Nikodym theorem, so probably we have to start from scratch to see that these are indeed true in the vector-valued case...

Thus my question is:

> What is a book that proves all standard theorems on integration theory (especially $L^p$ spaces, Radon–Nikodym, etc.) in the context of vector-valued functions, preferably building the theory *using* the real theory (instead of starting from scratch), and does not get too technical?

I know of books (e.g., *Real and Functional Analysis* by S. Lang) which does cover these, but he starts from scratch. I wonder if there is a quick way to build the theory using the real case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*Vector Measures* by Diestel and Uhl is the text that I learned from. I believe it checks the right boxes for you. It does get technical, however.